# How to use 2-factor auth with Bitbucket API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I have this code which use to work with the Bitbucket API (api.bitbucket.org), but it no longer works because I turned on 2-factor auth (which requires you to provide a code using your mobile phone).

```
const bitbucketBase64 = Buffer
  .from(`afills@teros.net:Gmm4br_*`)
  .toString('base64');

const request = https.get({ 

    protocol: 'https:',
    port: 443,
    hostname: 'api.bitbucket.org',
    path: pth,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Basic ${bitbucketBase64}`,
    }

  });
```

so is there a way to create a bitbucket account that has 2-factor auth but can still access the api programmatically? or should I turn-off 2 factor-auth for our bots that need to access the bitbucket api?

Comment: I hope that `Gmm4br_*` is not your actual password. If so, you should now change it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that the `App Passwords` are the ones you are looking for. Look at this for more information: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html

In short: `App Passwords` can be created on the Access management page of your user and then be used as normal Basic Authentication.

Comment: You've linked to Bitbucket Server documentation but OP is asking about Bitbucket Cloud. Try https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html instead.

Comment: Good catch @JimRedmond, thx. Always get confused with Server and Cloud questions. Edited my answer to fit to the Cloud version. Hope it is now correct.

Comment: No problem - it's a common mistake, based on what I see here. The easy tell is the hostname: `bitbucket.org`, `api.bitbucket.org`, and `bitbucket.com` are all BB Cloud; other hostnames are going to be BB Server (or really terrible DNS).

Comment: That's true. I actually also understood that it is about Cloud, because of the hostname, but didn't check my reference if it was about Server or Cloud. ^^